# Regex Match string prefix, but not multiple strings containing this prefix

Tags: regex

I need a regex which matches

```
any_
```

But which does not match any of the strings below

```
any_group1
any_group2
```

I tried

```
(?=.*any_.*)^((?!any_group1).)*$^((?!any_group1).)*$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well this should do it, using Negative Lookbehind:

```
\bany_.*(?<!group[1-2])\b$
```

[Regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/fel5hZ/1/).

Comment: Thanks  I used \bany_.*(?<!any_group2)\b$(?<!any_group1)\b$

Answer (score 1):

You might also use a negative lookahead `(?!` to assert what is on the right is not group1 or group2:

`\bany_(?!group[12]\b)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dIQ4W6/1)

That will match:

- `\b` Word boundary
- `any_` Match literally
- `(?!group[12]\b)` Negative lookahead to assert what is on the right is not group1 or group 2 followed by a word boundary